# How to check 3D touch available in iPhone programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, 3dtouch

I have my ios application I want to check how 3D touch available means (iPhone 6s or iPhone6s plus)?

so how can I check it?

Comment: Can you sand me link of this duplicate question???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should try this.

```
//check if the device supports 3DTouch
if(self.traitCollection.forceTouchCapability == UIForceTouchCapabilityAvailable){
    [self registerForPreviewingWithDelegate:self sourceView:self.view];
}else{
    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"3DTouch not available" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
}
```